# Не загружается компонент angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular2

Суть такова: имею `MainComponent`, `code`:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from "@angular/core";
import {WebSocketService} from "../services/websocket.service";
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Subscription} from "rxjs/Rx";
import {User} from "../../client/user.model";
import {NotificationComponent} from "../../notification/components/notification.component";
import {ToasterService, ToasterContainerComponent} from "angular2-toaster/angular2-toaster";

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    template: `<toaster-container></toaster-container>
<notification-component></notification-component>
<button (click)="popToast()">pop toast</button>`,
    providers: [WebSocketService, ToasterService],
    directives: [NotificationComponent, ToasterContainerComponent]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild(NotificationComponent) private notification: NotificationComponent;

    private sub: Subscription;
    private user: User;
    private toasterService: ToasterService;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private ws: WebSocketService,
                toasterService: ToasterService) {
        this.toasterService = toasterService;
        this.user = new User();
    }

    popToast() {
        this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Args Title', 'Args Body');
        this.notification.start({
            timeout: 50,
            type: 'info',
            title: 'Test Web Service',
            body: 1,
            buttonCloseShow: false
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.sub = this.route
            .params
            .subscribe(params => {
                this.user.room = params['room'];
                this.user.name = params['name'];
                this.user.lastname = params['lastname'];
            });

        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.ws = new WebSocketService();
        this.ws.run(this.onMessage);

        setTimeout(() =>
            this.ws.send({
                name: this.user.name,
                lastname: this.user.lastname,
                room: this.user.room,
                action: 'client_go_test'
            }), 500);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    onMessage(event: MessageEvent) {
        let routes: Object = {
            'go_test': (response) => {
                console.log(response)
            },
            'client_test_not_found': (response) => {
                //this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Args Title', 'Args Body');
                console.log(this.notification);
                this.notification.start({
                    type: 'info',
                    title: 'Test Web Service',
                    body: response,
                    buttonCloseShow: false
                });
            }
        };

        let data = JSON.parse(event.data);

        if (routes.hasOwnProperty(data.action)) {
            routes[data.action](data.response);
        }
    }
}
```

`NotificationComponent` `code`

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {TimerService} from "../services/timer.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'notification-component',
    template: `<div class="j-toast {{toastConfig.type}}" [ngStyle]="{'opacity': opacity}" (mouseenter)="onEnter()" (mouseleave)="onLeave()">
       <div *ngIf="toastConfig.buttonCloseShow" class="toast-close" (click)="close()">X</div>
    <div id="toast-progress" class="toast-progress" [ngStyle]="{'width': timerService.getWidth() + '%'}"></div>
    <div class="toast-content">
        <div class="toast-data">
            <div class="toast-title">{{toastConfig.title}}</div>
            <div class="toast-body">{{toastConfig.body}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>`,
    providers: [TimerService]
})
export class NotificationComponent {

    private opacity: number = 0;
    public toastConfig: Object = {};

    constructor(public timerService: TimerService) {}

    public start(config: Object) {
        this.opacity = 1;
        this.toastConfig = config;
        this.timerService.start(this.toastConfig['timeout']);
    }

    public close() {
        this.opacity = 0;
        this.timerService.close();
    }

    onEnter(): void {
        this.timerService.pause();
    }

    onLeave(): void {
        this.timerService.resume();
    }
}
```

когда я вызываю `popToast` нажатием на кнопку все `toast` работают, а вот если у меня приходит сообщение от сокетов (проблема не в сокетах) и я там вызываю

```
this.notification.start({
                    type: 'info',
                    title: 'Test Web Service',
                    body: response,
                    buttonCloseShow: false
                });
```

то получаю `TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая конструкция:

```
let x = new MyObject();
let y = x.printThing;
y()
```

теряет контекст `this`.

Это можно обойти двумя способами:

При передаче метода класса в качестве callback-функции создать дополнительное замыкание:

```
let y = () => x.printThing()
```

Или создать это замыкание сразу вместо метода класса:

```
class MyObject{
private status = "blah";
    public printThing = () => { // <-- 
        alert(this.status);
    }
}

...

let x = new MyObject();
let y = x.printThing
```

Comment: typescript эту проблему решает, я даже проверил, все тоже

Comment: а чему вообще равен this в момент когда приходит сообщение от сокетов?

Comment: посмотрите эту статью https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript с момента `Red Flags for this`. У вас ситуация очень похожа. Попробуйте объявить onMessage так как показано далее в блоке `Fixes`

Comment: я понял в чем соль, onMessage же callback вебсокетов this указывает на него даже как вы предлагали, как в этом случае быть ? сделать notification статическим ?

Comment: @jashka см. комментарий выше

Comment: спасибо, вопрос решен onMessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {

Comment: @jashka изменил ответ